# How to add contact from a rails app to salesforce using restforce gem?

Tags: salesforce

I am using [restforce gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) to connect to salesforce api. I have successfully connected to it and initialised the client using username/password like below

```
client = Restforce.new :username => 'foo',
  :password       => 'bar',
  :security_token => 'security token',
  :client_id      => 'client_id',
  :client_secret  => 'client_secret'
```

I am able to create Account in saleforce using the command that is given in gem docs

```
client.create('Account', Name: 'Foobar Inc.')
```

Now i want to know how to create contacts? I tried

```
client.create('Contact', Email: 'demo@example.com')
```

but it returns false.

Comment: Did you check the required fields in the contact object?, for example I believe that you need at least to provide the lastname. For example client.create('Contact', LastName: 'foobar', Email: 'demo@example.com')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried

```
client.create!('Contact', Email: 'demo@example.com')
```

which showed me the error that LastName is a required field as specified in the comment.

So the solution is to specify LastName also like shown below:

```
client.create('Contact', Email: 'demo@example.com', LastName: 'Bar')
```

Thanks and Happy Coding.